# query sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

Hola cuando hago una where en un include a la bd pero la relacion en la que estoy haciendo el include me devuelve un array me retorna solo los elementos del array q cumplan con esa condicion pero quisiera que me retornara si existen elementos en ese array que cumplen la condicion perfecto retorname todos

Comment: Bienvenido por favor lee [ask] y de paso checa el [tour], te recomiendo edites y  agregues lo que llevas así como los errores obtenidos al momento

Comment: Deberás explicarte mejor y en cualquier caso con código para ver lo que intentaste